# Is there any way to update the JSON file in Azure Blob storage whenever new data is added to JSON file in github or locally?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search, azure-bot-service

I am creating Azure Search Service and my dataset is a JSON file in Azure Blob Storage. I want to update it time to time so that the Search service is up to date.

I cant find any way of doing so. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in the correct format, you can use the JSON one to many indexer and set it to a regular schedule so that it will regularly and automatically refresh your data. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-json-blobs and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-one-to-many-blobs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Search SDK to do this. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-dotnet-sdk

1. Create an application that deserializes your JSON file to a collection of objects.
2. Use the Azure Search SDK to submit those objects to search.
3. Repeat as required to refresh the index.

Comment: Is there any way the json document automatically gets updated according to the json doc in github?

Comment: You can periodically refresh the data as explained in step 3. You can introduce a short delay and then check if your local/GitHub JSON file has changed since you last processed it before processing it again.

Comment: If you instead want an event based trigger to only refresh the index when changes occur in GitHub, you can use GitHub's webhooks and subscribe to repository changes.

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads